# Can't download mldata of sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_mldata
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.utils import shuffle
X_digits, _,_, Y_digits = fetch_mldata("MNIST Original").values()`
```

After running it, I get:

[image: Image description]

Comment: looks like a problem on the server side, can you download any other datasets from `mldata.org`?

Comment: As of now, mldata.org is down... you can check at https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/mldata.org

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the problem is temporary and related to mldata.org server. So try again later.

Answer (score 0):

So, it's the problem of the sever.
Next morning I can download...

Another way, after I downloading it I find the datafile name is *mnist-original.mat*, so you can go to gihub.com and search for the name to down the data file.